# Need help making a permutation faster

Tags: python, permutation

Here is my working code, I am trying to find ways to make it faster in finding the valid words, I was thinking about possibly making separate dictionary lists for each words, what do yall think?

```
import random
import itertools

file_name='words.txt'

def load_words():
    try:
        f=open(file_name,'r')
        str1=f.read()
        f.close()
    except:
        print('Problem opening the file',file_name)
    list1=[]
    list1=str1.split()
    return(list1)

def is_valid(str1,list1):
    valid=False
    if str1 in list1:
        valid=True
    return valid

def generate(words,letters):
    answers=[]
    for length in range(2,len(letters)+1):
        for x in itertools.permutations(letters,length):
            word=''
            for let in x:
                word+=let
            if is_valid(word.upper(),words):
                answers.append(word)
                print(word)
    print(answers)

def main():
    words=load_words()
    letters = input('Enter your letters')
    answers = generate(words,letters)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are too keen in increasing the speed at the cost of making it less readable you may try the following

```
def is_valid(str1,list1):
    return str1 in list1
words=["BAD","CAB","BEC"]
def generate2(words,letters):
    answers=[]
    [[answers.append(''.join(x).upper()) for x in itertools.permutations(letters,length) if ''.join(x).upper() in words] for length in range(2,len(letters)+1)]
    #print(answers)
    return answers
```

[List comprehension is faster than loops](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops). So combined both the loops to a single comprehension. Apart from that the statement

```
       word=''
        for let in x:
            word+=let
        if is_valid(word.upper(),words):
```

can be combined to if `is_valid(''.join(x).upper,words)` or even `''.join(x).upper in words`, remember function call is costly.

I have done a comparison in speed and looks list comprehension is running 50% faster.

Its now upto you to decide

---

```
>>> stmt1="""
def is_valid(str1,list1):
    valid=False
    if str1 in list1:
        valid=True
    return valid
words=["BAD","CAB","BEC"]
def generate1(words,letters):
    answers=[]
    for length in range(2,len(letters)+1):
        for x in itertools.permutations(letters,length):
            word=''
            for let in x:
                word+=let
            if is_valid(word.upper(),words):
                answers.append(word)
                #print(word)
    #print(answers)
    return answers
generate1(words,['A','B','C','D','E'])
"""
>>> 
>>> stmt2="""
def is_valid(str1,list1):
    return str1 in list1
words=["BAD","CAB","BEC"]
def generate2(words,letters):
    answers=[]
    [[answers.append(''.join(x).upper()) for x in itertools.permutations(letters,length) if ''.join(x).upper() in words] for length in range(2,len(letters)+1)]
    #print(answers)
    return answers
generate2(words,['A','B','C','D','E'])
"""
>>> 
>>> t1=timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt1)
>>> t2=timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt2)
>>> t1.repeat(number=1000)
>>> t2=timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt2)
>>> t1.repeat(number=1000)
[0.47923321640178074, 0.4353549521401874, 0.4362746333173959]
>>> t2.repeat(number=1000)
[0.2536238984591819, 0.2470974750062851, 0.24726312027155473]
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your `list1` to a set:

```
set1 = set(list1)
```

The testing `str1 in set1` will be **much** faster than `str1 in list1` if you do frequent tests and the list is long.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I don't feel it being any fast, if you take the program and run it with 7+ letters inputted you will see that it is substantially slow.

Comment: It's orders of magnitude faster as a set than a list.

Comment: @BrandonRutledge: don't rely on 'feel' to optimise a program. Use something like the 'timeit' module to test these assumptions. (http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, profile the code. That will tell you where the slow parts are.

Secondly, you might consider converting the words list to a set, which should have a faster 'in' operator for checking if the word is there.

Thirdly, consider simplifying the code to remove unnecessary statements, eg.

```
def is_valid(str1,list1):
   return str1 in list1
```

Comment: The slow part is when the valid words are 5 characters and larger, I believe I changed it to a set based on eumiro's comment but I felt no change in speed, also I don't understand your third statement.

Comment: The third suggestion is merely to clean up your code.  str1 in list1 returns a boolean True or False so you don't need an If ... return True else return False because the condition in the If evaluates to it so just return it.  It won't make your algorithm any faster to eliminate it, but it helps reduce code size and improve readability.

Comment: It might actually improve execution time, since redundant statements may still get executed, depending on how good a job Python does of compiling it all. But it's unlikely to have a significant effect: my main suggestion is still to profile the code.

Comment: Kylotan, what exactly do you mean by profiling, can you give me an example? thanks

Comment: Profiling is the act of automatically analysing your code to see what gets called, how often, and how long it takes. See also: http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?  It looks like you have some dictionary of valid words you are reading from already.  Why are you permutating all combination of words that could be built from the input given by the user?

Something you need to consider about your algorithm.  Every permutation you create you are iterating over every known word in your dictionary (list1).  When you create all permutations of the words you are creating m! words where m number of the letters given by the user.

You basically have O(n * m!).  That's ridiculously huge for even small number of things like 7.  By using a set, instead of a list, you can take that n term and reduce it to a constant which changes your algorithm to O(m!) which is still too big.  **If I had to guess what this algorithm is doing I'd say you want to know how many known words you can create out of the letters you are given**.  Again you didn't say that, but let's assume this is what you meant.

A faster algorithm would be to iterate over every word in your dictionary and see if you can make that word by picking letters from the input.  So you only walk over the dictionary once O(n * m).  That eliminates the need to permutate your input.  Here's the algorithm:

```
 user_input = input("Give me some words")
 for word in list1:
     current = user_input
     found = True
     for letter in word:
         if letter in current:
            current.remove( letter )
         else
            found = False
            break;
     if found:
        answers.add( word )
 print( answers )
```

Sorry my python is a little rusty but hopefully you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the inner loop with:

```
for x in itertools.permutations(letters,length):
    word = ''.join(x)
    if word.upper() in words:
        answers.append(word)
        print(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your algorithm is basically O(n * m!) where n is the word list size and m is number of letters. Changing the word list to a set should make the searches log time and **improve performance to O( log(n) * m!)** as recommended by other people here.

The real performance gain will however come from completely eliminating permuting the letters for the search. First sort the letters in each individual word in the word list alphabetically; it should take O( n * p log(p) ) time where p is average word length. Then sort the entire list alphabetically in O( n * log(n) ) time. Keep track of the original words as well, so that you can go from a string in the sorted word list to the original word in O(1). Next sort the imputed letters alphabetically and search for them in the sorted word list.

The slowest operation in the above algorithm is sorting the list of alphabetically sorted strings, which is O(n Log(n) ). Searching such a list is Log( n ) and results in **the entire algorithm executing in O( n Log(n) ) time**. It should scale linearly to m, the number of letters inputed.

Implementation is left to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to look up words often, you should build a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29) from your data.

Simple example follows. The code should be pretty self-explanatory, but please ask if something is unclear.

```
import pickle


class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.letters = dict()

    def add_words(self, words):
        for word in words:
            self.add_word(word)

    def add_word(self, word):
        chars = list(word.lower())
        l = chars.pop(0)
        try:
            self.letters[l].add_word(chars)
        except KeyError:
            self.letters[l] = Letter(l)
            self.letters[l].add_word(chars)

    def is_word(self, word):
        chars = list(word.lower())
        l = chars.pop(0)
        try:
            return self.letters[l].is_word(chars)
        except KeyError:
            return False


class Letter:
    def __init__(self, letter):
        self.letter = letter
        self.sub_letters = dict()
        self.is_a_word = False

    def add_word(self, word):
        if len(word) == 0:
            self.is_a_word = True
            return
        l = word.pop(0)
        try:
            self.sub_letters[l].add_word(word)
        except KeyError:
            self.sub_letters[l] = Letter(l)
            self.sub_letters[l].add_word(word)

    def is_word(self, word):
        if len(word) == 0:
            return self.is_a_word
        l = word.pop(0)
        try:
            return self.sub_letters[l].is_word(word)
        except KeyError:
            return False


def get_dict(obj_file, dict_file):
    try:
        with open(obj_file, 'rb') as my_dict:
            return pickle.load(my_dict)
    except IOError:
        my_tree = Tree()
        with open(dict_file, 'rb') as in_file:
            for word in in_file:
                my_tree.add_word(word.strip())
        with open(obj_file, 'wb') as outfile:
            pickle.dump(my_tree, outfile, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        return my_tree


obj_file = 'mydict.pk'
dict_file = 'wordlist.txt'
my_tree = get_dict(obj_file, dict_file)
```

**(There are a lot of different types of trees, this is just a very simple example)**

When the tree has been built, it will only require `len(word)` function calls to determine if the entered word is valid. This is a huge improvement from `if word in wordlist`, which takes `O(len(wordlist))`.

The downside with an approach like this, is that generating the tree may take some time. By serializing the `Tree()` object using [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), you don't have to build the tree each time you start your script.

I tried to build a tree using a wordlist from [SIL International](http://www2.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/) (total of 109582 words).

Timing it with [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), the execution time was reduced by ~50 % when unpickle the object file rather than build the dict from scratch.

If you'd like to only check for permutations, you should alter the `add_word()` method of `Tree()` to sort the letters in the first place. Input argument to `Tree.is_word()` should also of course be sorted.

Comment: ...and then I realize that this is a two years old question. Well, well.